# How to set Google Chrome to automatically open up and in full screen

Tags: google-chrome, tablet, fullscreen, kiosk

I have Dell Windows tablet (I think the model is the Venue 11 Pro) and when the tablet is turned on I want it to automatically open a specific web page (lets say cnn.com for example) using Google Chrome, and also display full screen.

Obviously it may show the desktop for a few seconds first while the tablet loads up before opening Chrome, but that's fine.

I have right-clicked the Chrome icon from my desktop and clicked Properties and in target it currently says

C:\Users\Tablet4\AppData\Local\Google|Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk https://cnn.com

this DOES open chrome automatically, however DOES NOT make it full screen.

To get full screen, I have to close the browser, then click on the Chrome icon again from the desktop, and then it goes full screen.. however I want it to open automatically AND go full screen the first time round.

I have also tried just the word --kiosk    and also --start-fullscreen but it still won't do both things I want it to do.

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: May I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649264/run-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode-on-windows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After realising that --kiosk mode just would not work at all for me on my tablet, I managed to find a workaround solution by combining these 3 steps.

STEP 1 (how to open Chrome in full screen)

- Right click (or tap and hold on tablet) on the Google Chrome icon from my desktop
- Select Properties
- Select Shortcut tab
- In Target box, change path to say "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen

STEP 2 (how to set the page you want Chrome to automatically open)

- Go back to desktop and click/tap Chrome icon (which should now open full screen)
- Tap and hold finger on screen and then tap the X to temporarily exit the full screen (or if you're using a keyboard, press F11)
- Select the 3 vertical dots (top right of screen)
- Select settings
- Go down to 'On Start-Up' section, check 'Open a specific page or set of
  pages' and enter the desired website/URL you want Chrome to open

STEP 3 (how to automatically open Chrome on start up)

- Press the Windows key and R together to open the run dialog (if using
  a tablet, search for the word 'run')
- Type in shell:startup and press OK, an explorer window will open up
- Copy and paste the Chrome icon from your desktop to this window
- Restart your device and Chrome should automatically launch (after 10
  seconds or so) AND display full screen.

Hope this helps someone who suffered the same frustration and hours of wasted time as me! :)

Comment: god bless you! I've been banging my head against the wall trying to make this work. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 3):

I just tried the below method, and it is working fine

1. Right click the shortcut
2. Select Properties
3. In Target field enter

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" —full-screen URL
   ```

This will open the URL in full screen.
However, to make it open automatically adding it into startup is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

For easy customization approach can use this VBScript and add it to start up if so wish or simply launch with shortcut or by clicking normally.

I used this approach because I used local html file to create a video player which requires fullscreen to run perfectly.

#### Below is my VBScript code which i named 'myurl.vbs'

This script launches **example.com** in **chrome** in **fullscreen mode**

```
siteA = "example.com"
Const OneSecond = 1000 
Set browobj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
browobj.Run "chrome --start-fullscreen -url "&siteA
Set browobj = Nothing
```

Change `example.com` to your `url` or `file location`
Delete `--start-fullscreen` if you don't require fullscreen
Separate multiple urls with space
e.g `siteA = "example.com google.com superuser.com stackoverflow.com"`

#### Below is my approach

1. I create text file `myurl.txt`
2. I pasted the above code and save the text
3. I renamed the file to `myurl.vbs`

#### Further approach if required Adding to startup

1. I pressed `WINDOW BUTTON + R` and typed `shell:startup`
2. It lauched the FILE EXPLORER and copied and pasted `myurl.vbs`
3. I restarted my tablet PC and it works perfectly till date.